# Using a distributed Airflow worker in a dedicated Docker environment

Tags: java, docker, airflow

We have an extraction job which executes Java code, that we encapsulated in a Dockerfile to keep our host machine clean.

Now we are considering introducing Airflow to automate this and other tasks . Our tasks run on different machines and should be scalable, so we want to execute everything inside docker containers. We use `RabbitMQ` for the queue and `MySQL` for the meta database.

Intuitively, I thought that installing a minimum Airflow python package dedicated to handling the `CeleryExecutor` part would be enough, but it seems, that any Airflow instance must hold a connection to the database, so it seems, that at the end I would have to use a similar (Docker) environment as the Airflow server/scheduler.

Now I was wondering if I have to inherit a base Airflow Image for every single job that I want to manage? In our case that would mean, that I have to get a little messy by installing the Java part on top of the inherited Airflow environment.

Do I really have to write custom Dockerfile parts for including Java or other environments where I would usually just inherit from a dedicated Docker image or is there another option that I dont see yet?

Starting docker inside docker is not an option in my opinion.